# How to draw plain lines instead of dotted lines for Grid ?

Tags: wpf

I have question how to make line and not the dotted line.

My code:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

[image: the dotted line]

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `Grid` that will draw the lines itself.

[image]

```
<wpfApplication5:MyGrid ShowGridLines="True">
    <wpfApplication5:MyGrid.GridLinesPen>
        <Pen Brush="DeepSkyBlue" Thickness="5" />
    </wpfApplication5:MyGrid.GridLinesPen>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</wpfApplication5:MyGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public class MyGrid : Grid
    {
        public new static readonly DependencyProperty ShowGridLinesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ShowGridLines", typeof (bool), typeof (MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));


        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLinesPenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "GridLinesPen", typeof (Pen), typeof (MyGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Pen), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public new bool ShowGridLines
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(ShowGridLinesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowGridLinesProperty, value); }
        }


        public Pen GridLinesPen
        {
            get { return (Pen) GetValue(GridLinesPenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridLinesPenProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            Pen pen = GridLinesPen;
            if (pen != null)
            {
                ColumnDefinitionCollection columnDefinitions = ColumnDefinitions;
                if (columnDefinitions.Count > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < columnDefinitions.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnDefinition columnDefinition = columnDefinitions[i];
                        double offset = columnDefinition.Offset;
                        dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(offset, 0), new Point(offset, RenderSize.Height - 1));
                    }
                }

                RowDefinitionCollection rowDefinitions = RowDefinitions;
                if (rowDefinitions.Count > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < rowDefinitions.Count; i++)
                    {
                        RowDefinition rowDefinition = rowDefinitions[i];
                        double offset = rowDefinition.Offset;
                        dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, offset), new Point(RenderSize.Width - 1, offset));
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }
    }
}
```

Note : by adding `new` to `ShowGridLines` I am circumventing the original behavior of that property.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each of the grid elements into a border and style it as you wish

(just so that's clear, you don't change your column/row définitions, leave them as is, but instead of putting whatever you wanted to put in each of those rows / columns, put a border and put the content Inside the border)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that each element should fill their cell in the grid which might not be desired, if the OP was using an ItemsControl then he could have done that easily using ItemContainerTemplate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: True but his drawing did show a uniformgrid pretty much